# How can I mock ActivityExecutionContext

Tags: mocking, moq

This class is sealed but I need to mock it using Moq for use in a CRM workflow development for calling the method:

```
    protected override ActivityExecutionStatus Execute(ActivityExecutionContext executionContext)
```

How can I do this or get around the problem by creating an instance of ActivityExecutionContext (which has no public constructor)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you have many options besides creating a wrapper/proxy you can use in your code, which you then can mock.

I'm not sure I understand your question right though, is the class in essence a singleton? If so [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/co-single.html)'s a great link explaining how to work around singletons when unit testing.

Is it possible for you to change the implementation of `Execute`?

Comment: Execute is an overridden method from within the workflow system. In the end I have just kept that element really thin and extracted the code to another testable class.